# Python and Pandas Creating Multiple Dynamic Excel Sheets with Dataframes

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, export-to-excel

Thanks in advance!  I have been struggling for a few days so that means it is time for me to ask a question.  I have a program that is pulling information for three stocks using the module "yfinance" It uses a ticker list in a txt file.  I can get the intended information into a data frame for each ticker in the list using a for loop.  I then want to save information for each separate ticker on its own *sheet* in an Excel *book* with the *sheet* name being the ticker.  As of now I end up creating three distinct data frames but the Excel output only has one tab with the last requested ticker information (MSFT).  I think I may need to use an append process to create a new tab with each data frame information, thanks for any suggestions.

**Code**

```
import platform
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import csv

# check versions
print('Python Version: ' + platform.python_version())
print('YFinance Version: ' + yf.__version__)

# load txt of tickers to list, contains three tickers
tickerlist = []
with open('tickers.txt') as inputfile:
    for row in csv.reader(inputfile):
        tickerlist.append(row)

# iterate through ticker txt file
for i in range(len(tickerlist)):
    tickersymbol = tickerlist[i]
    stringticker = str(tickersymbol)
    stringticker = stringticker.replace("[", "")
    stringticker = stringticker.replace("]", "")
    stringticker = stringticker.replace("'", "")

    # set data to retrievable variable
    tickerdata = yf.Ticker(stringticker)
    tickerinfo = tickerdata.info

    # data items requested
    investment = tickerinfo['shortName']
    country = tickerinfo['country']

    # create dataframes from lists
    dfoverview = pd.DataFrame({'Label': ['Company', 'Country'],
                          'Value': [investment, country]
                           })

    print(dfoverview)
    print('-----------------------------------------------------------------')

    #export data to each tab (PROBLEM AREA)
    dfoverview.to_excel('output.xlsx',
                        sheet_name=stringticker)
```

**Output**

Python Version: 3.7.7

YFinance Version: 0.1.54

Company   Walmart Inc.

### Country  United States

Company    Tesla, Inc.

### Country  United States

Company  Microsoft Corporation

### Country          United States

Process finished with exit code 0

EDITS: Deleted original to try and post to correct forum/location

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html

Comment: Thanks, I have read some documentation and will check this one out and let you know if it solves my issue.  This does mention an append item which unfortunately was not able to find searching.  Sometimes ya just miss stuff!  Will be in touch.

Comment: Often times I search a lot and miss a simple article that would have saved me time.  I did really try this for a couple days which is sad. I always try to do this before I ask. a question here. Somehow I tried all sorts of things but not this actual append link even though I knew to use the word "append."  That is sad on my part.  However, that quick link solved my problem so thank you and I am glad I came here.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your ticker information is in a single data frame, Pandas `groupby()` method works well for you here (if I'm understanding your problem correctly). This is pseudo, but try something like this instead:

```
import pandas as pd

# df here represents your single data frame with all your ticker info
# column_value is the column you choose to group by
# this column_value will also be used to dynamically create your sheet names
ticker_group = df.groupby(['column_value'])

# create the writer obj
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    # key=str obj of column_value, data=dataframe obj of data pertaining to key
    for key, data in ticker_group:
        ticker_group.get_group(key).to_excel(writer, sheet_name=key, index=False)
```